# SQLite: How to split a column

Tags: regex, sqlite

I have a column containing two names, which I'd like to extract into two separate columns `surname1` and `surname2` (I don't need the name nor the initial letter (e.g. `N.`)).

The exemplary content of that column is:

```
AwyeEaef2012 MS101 N.Lopez-O.Lorenzi.txt
```

-Lopez and Lorenzi are these two which we are looking for in this row.

What is good about my situation is that the first name comes always after the first dot (`.`) and ends just before the dash (`-`) and the second name comes just after second dot and ends just before the third dot and `txt` (`.txt`).

I know how to write a regex and using `LIKE` check if that column contains some specific surname but not the opposite way- how to read surnames and write them into two new columns.

Several rows from that column look like below:

```
WyeEaef MN2014 MS401 N.Lopez-O.Lorenzi.txt
AwyufEQ WCH2014 OS401 N.Lorenzi-O.Lopez.txt
THAFa5u WCH2014 LS107 N.Larry-O.Lolly.txt
```

So the pattern is as I mentioned `*.Name1-[A-Z].Name2.txt`

Where * is max 30 characters of capital and small letters and numbers

It could be approached in this manner: other words we need to divide this into substrings divided by dots first substring is a waste, the second without two last characters(a dash and acapital letter, e.g. -O) is the first name, the third substring is the second name and the fourth is another waste(a former file format).

I'd like to have an output of three columns:
initialColumn, firstName, secondName

Comment: Usually a table contains more than one row. What other values are in this column? Do they look similar? What is the desired output?

Comment: Answer is above in an edited post. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: What has the `max 30 characters`, the whole string, the characters before the names, the names?

Comment: Part marked as * . Useless part. Everything before the first dot.

Comment: Look for what is between the 2 **.**. Then split this by using **-** as separator

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that I wrote as a formula in Excel which I personally don't love, but might be useful for someone in the future.

```
=MID(A1;FIND(".";A1;1)+1;FIND(".";A1;FIND(".";A1;1)+1)-FIND(".";A1;1)-3)
```

I was surprised that Excel can manage processing ~0.5mln of records in the blink of an eye.